# Databricks - workspace import file api caused a file already exists exception

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-rest-api

I'm working on Databricks API that upload a notebook file from local with following api call

[image]

In normal behavior this code work just fine. There are some cased that if test.py already in the workspace but with different a language property e.g. SQL. API will throw this exception

`{"error_code":"RESOURCE_ALREADY_EXISTS","message":"Path (/Shared/Notebooks/test.py) already exists"`

I'm assumed that the "overwrite" should mean to allow any overwrite of duplication file. Have any one experience similar problem?

Comment: try `"overwrite": true`

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. This is seemed to work. I wonder "true" used to work.

Comment: I'm wondering where you found that it should be `"true"` as string?

Comment: from this page: https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/workspace/import

Comment: Ok, documentation is fixed, will be rolled out in the next days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@Alex Ott** suggested in comments Posting it as an answer to help other community members.

As per this updated [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/workspace/import)

> **Use `overwrite` as a Boolean type**, not as a string. it will specify whether to overwrite existing object or not.
>
> > ```json
> > "overwrite": true
> > ```

here is request sample:

```json
{
  "path": "string",
  "format": "SOURCE",
  "language": "PYTHON",
  "content": "string",
  "overwrite": true
}
```